# compare two characters based on subset

Tags: r, plyr

I have a simple dataframe with two columns:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,2,3), 
                 y = c(rep(1:2,2),1), 
                 target = c('a','a','a','b','a'))
```

I would like to compare the strings in the target column (find out whether they are equal or not, i.e., TRUE or FALSE) within every level of x (same number for x). 
First I would like to compare lines 1 and 2, then 3 and 4 ...
My problem is that I am missing some comparisons, for example, line 5 has only one case instead of two - so it should turn out to be FALSE.
Variable y indicates the first and second case within x.

I played around with ddply doing something like:

```
ddply(df, .(x), summarise,
        ifelse(as.character(df[df$y == '1',]$target), 
               as.character(df[df$y == '2',]$target),0,1))
```

which is ugly ...
and does not work ...

Any insights how I could achieve this comparison?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want it to be TRUE only if there are exactly 2 x's with that value (not 3 or more?)

Comment: Hmm, does that mean there can be more than 2 rows per subset? Or is there either 2 or < 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ddply(df, .(x), function(d) NROW(d) == 2 & d$target[1] == d$target[2])
```

This assumes you want the value to be TRUE only if there are exactly 2 rows with that 'x' value. If it is possible for there to be 3 or more, and you want it to be TRUE if all `target` values are identical, you could do:

```
ddply(df, .(x), function(d) NROW(d) > 1 & length(unique(d$target)) == 1)
```

Comment: this works exactly as intended
NROW = nrow I assume? thanks a lot for your quick response

Comment: No, `NROW()` and `nrow()` are two different functions. `NROW()` will treat a vector as if it were a 1-column matrix; if passed a vector `nrow()` would complain and throw an error. `NROW()` is a little more robust than `nrow()` when data are being subsetted etc. Essentially they do do the same thing however.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution, assuming I have followed what you wanted correctly. `foo()` is a function that compares the two `target` values in each subset, whilst we `split()` the data on `df$x` and `l|sapply()` `foo()` to each of the subsets.

```
foo <- function(x) {
    with(x, {if(length(target) < 2) {
                 FALSE
             } else {
                 isTRUE(all.equal(target[1], target[2]))
             }})
}
lapply(split(df, df$x), foo)

sapply(split(df, df$x), foo)
```

Which produces this output

```
> lapply(split(df, df$x), foo)
$`1`
[1] TRUE

$`2`
[1] FALSE

$`3`
[1] FALSE

> 
> sapply(split(df, df$x), foo)
    1     2     3 
 TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Gavin, this works as intended - thanks. I slightly prefer David's answer, as the code is very compact and I like using ddply ... no really good reason against your solution ... I know

Answer (score 1):

```
 ave(as.character(df$target), df$x, 
     FUN=function(z) if ( length(z)=="2" & length(unique(z))==1){TRUE} else{ FALSE })
[1] "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE"
```

Or ... if you only want the results by group ...., use aggregate:

```
>  aggregate(as.character(df$target), list(df$x), 
+      FUN=function(z) if ( length(z)=="2" & length(unique(z))==1){TRUE} else{ FALSE })
  Group.1     x
1       1  TRUE
2       2 FALSE
3       3 FALSE
```

Comment: the result vector should be length=3 because unique(x) = 3
the check is always for pairs of unique(x)